# Find the Fourier series of $g(x)=f(x+a)$, when given $C_n$ the complex coefficients of $f$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am having trouble solving this questions:

"Let $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty{{c_n}{e^{-inx}}} $ be the Fourier series of $f(x)$.
find the Fourier series of $g(x)=f(x+a)$".

I have tried to start from the definition for $g(x)$ complex coefficients ($D_n$) and extract $f(x)$ complex coefficients ($C_n$).

I have ended up with an expression very close to what I want but with non matching integration limits.
I would appreciate any suggestions or solution to this problem :) .

what I have so far:

$D_n$
$= \frac{1}{{2\pi}} \int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi{g(x)e^{-inx}}dx $
$= \frac{1}{{2\pi}} \int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi{f(x+a)e^{-inx}}dx$
$= \begin{Bmatrix}t=x+a\\ds=dt\\ \end{Bmatrix}$
$= \frac{1}{{2\pi}} \int\limits_{-\pi+a}^{\pi+a}{f(t)e^{-in(t-a)}}dt$
$= \frac{e^{ina}}{{2\pi}} \int\limits_{-\pi+a}^{\pi+a}{f(t)e^{-int}}dt$

Answer (score 1):

The integral is an interval that has length $2\pi$ so it gives you the wanted result at the end $e^{ina}C_n$.